# D3.js treemap wrong rectangle size

Tags: d3.js, treemap

i'm currently working on an interactive D3.js Treemap, strongly inspired from https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-treemap. However I got a problem with the size of inner rectangle on the composing part of "Maxillopoda" group as you can see in
https://jsfiddle.net/CharlotteAndre/rjy2pb4x/4/ the last "Halopitilus" group is larger than many groups even if I got a value of 1. The problem might be coming from this function

```
function position(group, root) {
        group.selectAll("g")
            .attr("transform", d => d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("width", d => d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))
            .attr("height", d => d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0));
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue with your treemap building using value of nodes and sort function

let treemap = data => d3.treemap()
.tile(tile)(d3.hierarchy(data)
**.sum(d => d.value)
.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value))**

When you are sorting based on sum of values, dont assign 0 value to parent nodes. I changed your data to remove the values associated with parents. Either you assign sum of children values or dont assign. This logic will mess up your hierarchy. Run the code below and let me know if this suffice on what you want. I have changed the width and height for better viewing.

```js
let data = {
    "name": "Crustacea",

    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Maxillopoda",

            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Maxillopoda_X",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Maxillopoda_X_sp.",
                            "value": 448
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Acartia",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_longiremis",
                            "value": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_negligens",
                            "value": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_danae",
                            "value": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_pacifica",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pleuromamma",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Pleuromamma_scutullata",
                            "value": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Pleuromamma_borealis",
                            "value": 8
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Calocalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_minutus",
                            "value": 143
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_sp.",
                            "value": 61
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_plumulosus",
                            "value": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_pavo",
                            "value": 19
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mecynocera",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Mecynocera_clausi",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Oithona",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Oithona_sp.",
                            "value": 18
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Corycaeus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Corycaeus_speciosus",
                            "value": 9
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Acrocalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Acrocalanus_monachus",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subeucalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Subeucalanus_crassus",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sapphirina",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_sp.",
                            "value": 9
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_scarlata",
                            "value": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_darwinii",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Paracalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Paracalanus_aculeatus",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Canthocalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Canthocalanus_pauper",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Temoropia",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Temoropia_mayumbaensis",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cosmocalanus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Cosmocalanus_darwinii",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Haloptilus",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Haloptilus_longicornis",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Undinula",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Undinula_vulgaris",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Centropages",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Centropages_violaceus",
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Euchaeta",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Euchaeta_indica",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

let svg_element = document.getElementById('treemap');
      this.svg = d3.select(svg_element);


      let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // let height = 400;
      // let width = 500;
      let format = d3.format("");
      let uids = new Map();
      let uid = title => {
        let counter = uids.has(title) ? uids.get(title) + 1 : 0;
        uids.set(title, counter);
        return `${title}-${counter}`;
      }
      

      let name = d => d.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/");

      function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
        d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
        for (const child of node.children) {
          child.x0 = x0 + child.x0 / width * (x1 - x0);
          child.x1 = x0 + child.x1 / width * (x1 - x0);
          child.y0 = y0 + child.y0 / height * (y1 - y0);
          child.y1 = y0 + child.y1 / height * (y1 - y0);
        }
      }
      let treemap = data => d3.treemap()
          .tile(tile)(d3.hierarchy(data)
              .sum(d => d.value)
              .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value))



      const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

      const svg = this.svg
          .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
          .style("font", "8px sans-serif");

      let group = svg.append("g")
          .call(render, treemap(data));

      function render(group, root) {

        const node = group
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(root.children.concat(root))
            .join("g");

        node.filter(d => d === root ? d.parent : d.children)
            .attr("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("click", (event, d) => d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d));

        node.append("title")
            .text(d => `${name(d)}\n${format(d.value)}`)
            .style("font-size", "70%");


        node.append("rect")
            .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = uid("leaf")))
            .attr("fill", d => d === root ? "#edf3f7" : d.children ? "#0b9ba3" : "#0b9ba3")
            .attr("stroke", "#edf3f7");

        node.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = uid("clip")))
            .append("use")
            .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

        node.append("text")
            .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
            .attr("font-weight", d => d === root ? "bold" : null)
            .selectAll("tspan")
            .data(d => (d.data.name).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g).concat(format(d.value)))
            .join("tspan")
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("y", (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + 1.1 + i * 0.9}em`)
            .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
            .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null)
            .text(d => d);

        group.call(position, root);
      }

      function position(group, root) {
        group.selectAll("g")
            .attr("transform", d => d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("width", d => d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))
            .attr("height", d => d === root ? 20 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0));
      }

      // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
      function zoomin(d) {
        const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
        const group1 = group = svg.append("g").call(render, d);

        x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
        y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

        svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
                .call(position, d.parent))
            .call(t => group1.transition(t)
                .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
                .call(position, d));
      }

      // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
      function zoomout(d) {
        const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
        const group1 = group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent);

        x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
        y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);

        svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
                .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
                .call(position, d))
            .call(t => group1.transition(t)
                .call(position, d.parent));
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.4/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg id="treemap"></svg>
```

**UPDATE  without changing data**

```js
let data = {
    "name": "Crustacea",
    "value": 0,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Maxillopoda",
            "value": 195,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Maxillopoda_X",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Maxillopoda_X_sp.",
                            "value": 448
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Acartia",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_longiremis",
                            "value": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_negligens",
                            "value": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_danae",
                            "value": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Acartia_pacifica",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pleuromamma",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Pleuromamma_scutullata",
                            "value": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Pleuromamma_borealis",
                            "value": 8
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Calocalanus",
                    "value": 9,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_minutus",
                            "value": 43
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_sp.",
                            "value": 61
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_plumulosus",
                            "value": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Calocalanus_pavo",
                            "value": 19
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mecynocera",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Mecynocera_clausi",
                            "value": 11
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Oithona",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Oithona_sp.",
                            "value": 18
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Corycaeus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Corycaeus_speciosus",
                            "value": 9
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Acrocalanus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Acrocalanus_monachus",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subeucalanus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Subeucalanus_crassus",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sapphirina",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_sp.",
                            "value": 9
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_scarlata",
                            "value": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sapphirina_darwinii",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Paracalanus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Paracalanus_aculeatus",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Canthocalanus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Canthocalanus_pauper",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Temoropia",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Temoropia_mayumbaensis",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cosmocalanus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Cosmocalanus_darwinii",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Haloptilus",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Haloptilus_longicornis",
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Undinula",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Undinula_vulgaris",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Centropages",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Centropages_violaceus",
                            "value": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Euchaeta",
                    "value": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Euchaeta_indica",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

let svg_element = document.getElementById('treemap');
      this.svg = d3.select(svg_element);


      let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 198 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // let height = 400;
      // let width = 500;
      let format = d3.format("");
      let uids = new Map();
      let uid = title => {
        let counter = uids.has(title) ? uids.get(title) + 1 : 0;
        uids.set(title, counter);
        return `${title}-${counter}`;
      }
      

      let name = d => d.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/");

      function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
        d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
        for (const child of node.children) {
          child.x0 = x0 + child.x0 / width * (x1 - x0);
          child.x1 = x0 + child.x1 / width * (x1 - x0);
          child.y0 = y0 + child.y0 / height * (y1 - y0);
          child.y1 = y0 + child.y1 / height * (y1 - y0);
        }
      }
      function identifyLeaves(obj) {
        var hasNoChildren = (obj.children) ? false : true;
      if(hasNoChildren)
      return obj.value
      
}
   let treemap = data => d3.treemap()
          .tile(tile)(d3.hierarchy(data)
              .sum((d) => identifyLeaves(d))
              .sort((a, b) => identifyLeaves(b) - identifyLeaves(a)))
          



      const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

      const svg = this.svg
          .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
          .style("font", "8px sans-serif");

      let group = svg.append("g")
          .call(render, treemap(data));

      function render(group, root) {


        const node = group
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(root.children.concat(root))
            .data(root.children.concat(root))
            .join("g");

        node.filter(d => d === root ? d.parent : d.children)
            .attr("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("click", (event, d) => d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d));

        node.append("title")
            .text(d => `${name(d)}\n${format(d.value)}`)
            .style("font-size", "70%");


        node.append("rect")
            .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = uid("leaf")))
            .attr("fill", d => d === root ? "#edf3f7" : d.children ? "#0b9ba3" : "#0b9ba3")
            .attr("stroke", "#edf3f7");

        node.append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = uid("clip")))
            .append("use")
            .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

        node.append("text")
            .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
            .attr("font-weight", d => d === root ? "bold" : null)
            .selectAll("tspan")
            .data(d => (d.data.name).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g).concat(format(d.value)))
            .join("tspan")
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("y", (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + 1.1 + i * 0.9}em`)
            .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
            .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null)
            .text(d => d);

        group.call(position, root);
      }

      function position(group, root) {
        group.selectAll("g")
            .attr("transform", d => d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("width", d => d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))
            .attr("height", d => d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0));
      }

      // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
      function zoomin(d) {
        const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
        const group1 = group = svg.append("g").call(render, d);

        x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
        y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

        svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
                .call(position, d.parent))
            .call(t => group1.transition(t)
                .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
                .call(position, d));
      }

      // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
      function zoomout(d) {
        const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
        const group1 = group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent);

        x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
        y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);

        svg.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
                .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
                .call(position, d))
            .call(t => group1.transition(t)
                .call(position, d.parent));
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.4/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-hnFpvCiJ8Fr1lYLqcw6wLgFUOEZ89kWCkO+cEekwcWPIPKyknKV1eZmSSG3UxXfsSuf+z/SgmiYB1zFOg3l2UQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<svg id="treemap"></svg>
```

Comment: Well, in fact I wasn't assigning sum of children value or not, I have in fact data coming for oceanographic campaign and long story short sometimes scientist can say they've seen crabs and sometimes just arthropods... when i just have value for arthropods i can't remove the binded value... But can we admit that if I give all cumulated value for each parent node it will work ?

Comment: I have changed the function for treemap without changing anything in data, we make tree hierarchy based on leaf nodes only in this code. Hope this will work. If we give computed value for each parent, we will have to change the treemap function again. But to have integrity in hierarchical data, keep the values only on leaves because treemap assumes that parent value will be sum of children. Else mark the values with some another key-e.g reportedValue

Comment: Thanks for your help, hierarchy have been improved a lot ! I just need to find a way to add my middle value, maybe as leaf "other". :)

Comment: You can add a middle value as child to parent node and parent to leaf, it can make a n-level tree, with n having no limit.

Comment: I changed a little bit my data by removing value in parent node and add new leaf "Other", containing supp data, treemap is way more better. Thanks a lot for your explanations